# SQL select WHERE AND AND

Tags: mysql

I have a product page and when you click on add to basket

```
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$size= $_POST["length"];
$Category = $_POST['Category'];
```

It runs a POST method, posting those above. From that price can be selected based on the length. Because the category is a drop down menu... I am posting whatever category the user have selected.

Below are examples of my 3 tables and the query. Hope that helps
Table:Product

```
  Pid     Name
   1      man
   2      woman
   3      child
```

Table :Category

```
CatID  Name          Pid
1       pen           1
2       pen           1
3       pencil        2
3       red_pen       3
```

Table active_product

```
ATpid  size pid   price
 1      12   1     10
 2      14   2     15
 3      16   3     20
 4      18   4     30
```

My Query that i have tried

```
SELECT Name, size, price
FROM active_product, Product, Category
WHERE Product.pid=1
AND size=10  AND Name.Category=pen Limit 1
```

The query is not working. How can I improve it please?

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error? Unexpected results?

Comment: Be more specific than "not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have this:

```
SELECT Product.Name, size, price
FROM active_product, Product, Category
WHERE Product.pid=1
AND size=10  AND Category.Name="pen" Limit 1
```

Name is not a table.

Comment: Roma I have tried it but i get #1052 - Column 'Name' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @user2510447: I covered that in the *first sentence* in my answer.

Comment: you should update your query in your question, did you fix "pen"?

Comment: @nevermind is right, are you selecting Product.Name or Category.Name?

Comment: @A.S.Roma Thanks hope I didn't take too much of your time

Comment: @A.S.Roma because i am running that query for a webpage i have a problem and it is 
 $product_name = $row["Name"];

It is meant to echo the Name from the Product Table but instead it is echo out the Name from the Category. I have added Product.Name to the query and still echo out the Category Name. Will the best approach to this be to change the Name from the Category table or is they a way around this?

Comment: you can make another question and show some more of your code. This is another question, and comment me back the link of your question, I will look at it

Answer (score 0):

1) You forgotten about quotes

2) You should describe Name from which table - you use.

```
SELECT Category.Name, size, price
FROM active_product, Product, Category
WHERE Product.pid=1
AND size=10  AND Name.Category="pen" Limit 1
```

Comment: I have tried it but i get #1052 - Column 'Name' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You have two name columns (one in `product` and one in `category`), but you don't specify which one you want in your column list. You have no table called `Name`, so there can be no `Name.Category` in your `WHERE` clause, and if there were you'd need to specify `Name = 'pen'` (see the `'` around the value).

It appears you should really be looking for an SQL tutorial site somewhere, as these are really basic mistakes. Google and Bing can probably find one for you. Also, for future reference, posting things here with vague statements like "it doesn't work" with no explanation of what that means usually causes the question to be closed.